# Concat array elements into new array

Tags: arrays, jsonnet

I have a string which is separated by `"/"`, which I then split into an array. eg.

```
local string = 'Code/Github/Exercises'
local array = std.split(string, "/")

// ['Code', 'Github', 'Exercises']
```

How do I then convert `array` so that I can get the output:

```
// ['Code', 'Code/Github', 'Code/Github/Exercises']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet implements it, using `std.foldl()` as "iterator" to visit each element and build returned array

```
local string = 'Code/Github/Exercises';
local array = std.split(string, '/');


// If `array` length > 0 then add `elem` to last `array` element (with `sep`),
// else return `elem`
local add_to_last(array, sep, elem) = (
  local len = std.length(array);
  if len > 0 then array[len - 1] + sep + elem else elem
);

// Accumulate array elements, using std.foldl() to visit each elem and build returned array
local concat(array) = (std.foldl(function(x, y) (x + [add_to_last(x, '/', y)]), array, []));

concat(array)
```